# With zapier & Google Sheets: How do I trigger a new line in the entire spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, automation, spreadsheet, zapier

I'm a bit puzzled. I can't set Zapier to trigger when a new line is added to any sheet on a Google spreadsheet. They force you to choose a specific sheet. Any way around it?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a different "Zap" event for each sheet. To my knowledge, there is no way around that.

However, the fact that you think Zapier *should* be able to have a single Zap be triggered by multiple sheets implies a couple or things:

1.) You're not yet sure what a "Zap" is.

2.) Your data in each separate sheet is very similar. And this causes me to wonder if your overall spreadsheet setup is less than ideal. Many people wind up setting up separate sheets for data collection, whereas in most cases, data collection should only be done in *one* sheet setup as a standard database, while other sheets *show* the data in different arrangements (i.e., reports).

You haven't given much detail or provided a link to the spreadsheet. But perhaps this will prompt you to dive into understanding Zapier a bit better and reconsidering the layout of your spreadsheet(s).